# How to configure PHPmailer to sendmail and Gmail for localhost?

Tags: php, sendmail, phpmailer

I've been looking for answer more than a week. Im stuck with this problem. I have downloaded sendmail folder and configure it. Yes it says true message sent but actually it doesnt went to the mail. So I decided to put PHPmailer as I have read at some websites. i downloaded PHPmailer and configure it also. and when I am running it there is an error. Fatal error: Class 'SMTP' not found in C:\wamp\www\Project\PHPMailer\class.phpmailer.php on line 1197.
And I have also read some solution that paste the code before the line 104 #connectto the smtp server. but my line 104 looks like this. 
 public $CRLF = "\r\n";

```
/**
 * Debug output level.

 * Options:
 * * self::DEBUG_OFF (`0`) No debug output, default
 * * self::DEBUG_CLIENT (`1`) Client commands
 * * self::DEBUG_SERVER (`2`) Client commands and server responses
 * * self::DEBUG_CONNECTION (`3`) As DEBUG_SERVER plus connection status
 * * self::DEBUG_LOWLEVEL (`4`) Low-level data output, all messages
 * @type integer
 */
public $do_debug = self::DEBUG_OFF;
```

Can you help me guys. Im stuck here.

Comment: what is the debug code in reference to? PHPMailer has a debug function does that give any more clues?

Comment: You just need to [read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting), follow any of the examples provided; you need to use the autoloader or load the SMTP class yourself to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the newest PHPMailer with the autoloader?

See https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer as the mailer no longer calls the SMTP class from within the PHPMailer class. This was a pain when I updated as calling the mailer directly produced this error.

Also turn on PHPMailers debugging feedback and see what it says.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sendMail() method that I use in a lot of projects. It uses PHPMailer.

```
    function sendMail($toAddress, $subject, $body, $AttachmentFilePath) {
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP ();
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    // nable SMTP debugging
    // 0 = off (for production use)
    // 1 = client messages
    // 2 = client and server messages
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0; // To prevent any outpur
    // Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
    // Get the hostname of the mail server
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    // Get the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
    $mail->Port = 587;
    // Get the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    // Whether to use SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;

    // Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
    $mail->Username = "your.email@gmail.com";
    // Password to use for SMTP authentication. Specific to the Lead Qualifier Tool
    $mail->Password = "YourPassWordHere";

    // Set who the message is to be sent from
    $mail->SetFrom ( 'your.email@gmail.com', 'Your Name' );

    // To Address
    $mail->AddAddress ( $toAddress, $toAddress );

    $mail->Subject = $subject;

    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->AltBody = $body;

    // Add attachment
    if ($AttachmentFilePath != NULL)
        $mail->AddAttachment ( $AttachmentFilePath );

    if (! $mail->Send ()) {
        echo "<br />Error while sending e-mail: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        // echo "Message sent!";
    }
}
```

Hope it helps! :-)

Also, since you are using GMail, make sure you create an ASP(Application Specific Password), and use it here, and not your real password.

Comment: @DaniloEscapa Could you tell me what is the error you are facing?

Comment: Try passing something in the $body parameter. you should see it the reciepient's inbox.

Comment: Message was not sent 
PHPMailer Error: The following From address failed: verbz95@gmail.com : Called Mail() without being connected

Comment: Let's continue this in chat.

Comment: Let us continue here => http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69778/phpmailer-description